# I can't understand how this program is being executed

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is a javascript code snippet. I don't understand how only '5' is being printed at the output. That too only once.

Here is the code :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000 * i);
}
```

output - `5`.

Shouldn't `1,2,3,4` be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it doesn't print 5 once but 5 times each at an interval of 1 sec

```js
for(var i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
 setTimeout( function() {
 console.log(i) ; }, 1000*i);
}
```

It happens because the timeout function callbacks are all running well after the completion of the loop. In fact, as timers go, even if it was `setTimeout(.., 0)` on each iteration, all those function callbacks would still run strictly after the completion of the loop, that's why `5` was reflected as that will be the last value of `i` in the loop. Each of the timer handler functions will share the same variable "i"

If you want to seperate value each time. you can call a separate function in it passing `i` as a value and hence each will have a different value

```js
function checkTimeout(i) {
      setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*i);
    }
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
      checkTimeout(i);
    }
```